# jQuery toggle() malfunction on version upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function like this;

```
$('#mybutton').toggle(function() {
  alert("a");
}, function() {
  alert("b");
});
```

This was working fine with jQuery 1.3.2 . Recently I've upgraded jQuery to 1.11.0 . Then the page alerts `b` immediately after page load, and the button is disappearing. How can I fix this?

Here are the demos;

**[Old](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/Rk7Sv/)** and **[new](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/Rk7Sv/1/)**.

Comment: what button is disappearing?

Comment: @davidkonrad: He's talking about the button to which the handlers were intended to be bound. The one with the ID `mybutton`. Because `.toggle()` can no longer be used for event handers, the button simply gets hidden. The two answers below explain more, though for some reason they were both downvoted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use the [toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed on jQuery 1.9. The new toggle function has many different overloads, but none that behaves like the old one. [Take a look at it](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and choose the one that suits you the most. For example, you could do something like this:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
   if($('element').is(':visible')) {

    } else {

    }
});
```